# First/Third angle projection symbol in drawing sheet format

Tags: solidworks

is there any inbuilt feature in Solidworks to appropriately add the symbol for First/ third angle projection into the sheet format as per our selection?

[image]

Comment: the symbols under discussion: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiview_orthographic_projection#Symbol

Answer (score 1):

These symbols are built in to the default ISO and ANSI templates provided by SolidWorks, and you can copy/paste them from there into your own template. Alternatively, simply draw your own - it's just a few lines and circles!

Comment: Hi, I couldn't locate the inbuilt symbol with the default sheet templates. It seems the only way would be to manually add the symbol in the form of circles and lines. I was looking for a more automated way. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your default ISO template? Mine has the symbols